# How to add XML boolean attribute with lowercase value

Tags: powershell

Have a powershell code:

```
$source = @{ Param1 = $true; Param2 = "SomeString"; Param3 = 51 }

[System.XML.XMLDocument]$document = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
[System.XML.XMLElement]$rootElement = $document.CreateElement("Params")

foreach($key in $source.Keys)
{
   [System.XML.XMLElement]$elem = $document.CreateElement("Param")

   $elem.SetAttribute("Name", $key)
   $elem.SetAttribute("Value", $source[$key])

   $rootElement.appendChild($elem)
}
```

But in result XML I have:

```
<Params>
  <Param Name="Param1" Value="True" />
  ...
<Params>
```

"True" - isn't compatible with XMl standard. I expected lowcase "true". How can I do this in common way without type checking in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToLower()` method that works for strings, so first convert the value into a string:

```
$elem.SetAttribute("Value", "$($source[$key])".ToLower())
```

The `"$($source[$key])"` makes sure that nonexistent properties will be properly converted to an empty string, as well as other types such as Boolean will be stringified.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do the type checking thing, you can just escape with try / catch to see if the conversion succeeded or not.

```
Try
{
    $elem.SetAttribute("Value", $source[$key].ToLower())
}
Catch
{
    # No String
    $elem.SetAttribute("Value", $source[$key])
}
```

You can try this snipped

Comment: No need for try/catch: `$elem.SetAttribute("Value", "$($source[$key])".ToLower())`

Comment: @wOxxOm yup, that's the right way (you should post an answer). The try/catch example will always fail for boolean hashtable values